# Comparing two maps to calculate precision and recall for NER

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, precision-recall

I am trying to calculate precision and recall for our Named Entity Recognizer by comparing our output to a gold set output. annotationMap is the gold set map and myMap is the output of my NER.To give you a sense, the maps contain data like:

```
{ORGANIZATION=[Pearl Williams Hartsfield, Fulton Superior Court],
DATE=[Friday], PERSON=[William B. Hartsfield]}
```

According to an answer I had read here at stack overflow, the way we calculate precision and recall is (copy pasting from there):

```
[Microsoft Corp.] CEO [Steve Ballmer] announced the release of [Windows 7] today
```

This has 3 entities.

Supposing your actual extraction has the following

```
[Microsoft Corp.] [CEO] [Steve] Ballmer announced the release of Windows 7 [today]
```

**Exact match:** True Positives = 1 (Microsoft Corp., the only exact match), False Positives =3 (CEO, today, and Steve, which isn't an exact match), False Negatives = 2 (Steve Ballmer and Windows 7)

```
Precision = True Positives / (True Positives + False Positives) = 1/(1+3) = 0.25
Recall = True Positives / (True Positives + False Negatives) = 1/(1+2) = 0.33
```

**Any Overlap OK:** True Positives = 2 (Microsoft Corp., and Steve which overlaps Steve Ballmer), False Positives =2 (CEO, and today), False Negatives = 1 (Windows 7)

```
Precision = True Positives / (True Positives + False Positives) = 2/(2+2) = 0.55
Recall = True Positives / (True Positives + False Negatives) = 2/(2+1) = 0.66
```

I have modeled my code on the same logic but the value of false positives for me is always zero as a result my precision and recall values are 1 and 0 respectively.

I think the way I am calculating false positives is incorrect. But I am following the same logic and checking to see if I have any entities in myMap that are not contained in the annotatioMap and calling them false positive (like CEO and today in the example above). As a result I am confused as to where the problem exactly is!

```
private static List<Integer> compareMaps(LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> annotationMap, LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> myMap) 
        {
            List<Integer> compareResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
                if (annotationMap != null && myMap != null){
                   for (String key: annotationMap.keySet()){
                       if (key.equals("ORGANIZATION")){
                           if (annotationMap.get(key).equals(myMap.get(key))){
                               orgTruePositiveCount++;
                               continue;
                           }
                           if (annotationMap.get(key).contains(myMap.get(key))){
                               orgFalseNegativeCount++;
                               continue;
                           }
                           if (!annotationMap.get(key).contains(myMap.get(key))){
                               orgFalseNegativeCount++;
                               continue;
                           }
                           if (!myMap.get(key).contains(annotationMap.get(key))){
                               orgFalsePositiveCount++;
                               continue;
                           }
                       }
```